# Clustering Algorithm without calculating distance

Tags: clustering

I have two sets of points : A. The home lat and long of the customer (approx 1000) and B. The existing stops of bus in a route ( approx 500). I want to find the nearest stop to a particular customer.

However, I do not want to calculate the distance of each of the home coordinate with each of the stop coordinate. [ For 1 home location that means 500 distance computation. For 2000 stops it would mean 2000 distance computation and so on]

One logic I thought was:I want to get all the points in 300 m radius of one home coordinate and then find distance from those points in the 300 m radius and the one with minimum distance will be m nearest point. But how do I execute this ?

I am looking for a clustering method to find the nearest stop to a customer so that the run time is not exponentially affected by increase in the number of stops or home of customer .

Comment: What information do you assume to get here?